# Populate a 2nd date field min date from a previous date field in webform before submission

Tags: drupal-webform

I have 2 date fields on a webform. The 1st date field has a min date set

```
first_date:
  '#type': date
  '#title': 'First Date'
  '#date_date_min': 'today + 3 days'
  '#datepicker': true
  '#date_date_format': 'l, F j, Y'
```

The 2nd date field needs to be populated with a minimum date, reflecting the date entered into the 1st date field so that the user cannot select a date before the date entered into the 1st date field.

```
second_date:
  '#type': date
  '#title': 'Second Date'
  '#datepicker': true
  '#date_date_format': 'l, F j, Y'
```

As in the image below, the user can select a date for the 2nd date field before the date entered into the 1st date field.

This needs to happen on the form entry before the **form is submitted.**

Is this possible within the scope of the Webform module or does it require some javascript?

[image]

I have read that this is possable using the `function drupal_process_states`

I'm not a coder.  Just asking for help / direction. Thanks